# How do I insert html tags/script to sql as a text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I'm trying to work on a 'practice' app wherein the textbox value will be inserted to the database.

What happen is that when I insert the textbox.text value.

Ex. text =

```
           <script>alert('Hello')</script>
```

I get an error: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (TextBox1="alert('XSS')...").

I'm already using sql parameters so values like ' " /// \\ are not a problem as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set **ValidateRequest="false"** for your page, for allowing html.

At page level:

```
<%@ Page Language="c#"  ValidateRequest="false" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestPage" %>
```

Also, for ASP.NET 4.0, you need to add the following to your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: Setting `ValidateRequest="false"` for page will make security aspects of that page weaker, I would recommend HTML editor controls instead.

Comment: Thank you(Thanks++) for the immediate reply sir, but is it possible to do it without changing those values that you stated above. (I'm just curious if it's possible) :D

Answer (score 1):

If is only for testing purposes you may disallow ASP.NET validator so it will stop looking for HTML/XML tags that could be potentially dangerous. To do that, set ValidateRequest to false in your aspx page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false"
```

This is not recommended for production environments but in your case can do the trick. More info in the following [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a (potential) sql problem that asp.net is warning about. When you accept that value and later show it in your page **without encoding**, then that unwanted script will fire.

At this moment it will show a harmless alert, but if you allow any user to type in these values then who knows what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert the tag broken in a concatenate string. like in:

```
Insert into table values('<'+'h2'+'>'+'Another One'+'<'+'/'+'h2'+'>')
```